# SQL. Указать app_name перед выполнением запроса

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возник вопрос, после подключения к ms SQL требуется указать app_name для выполняемой транзакции, для следующего запроса, другой app_name.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И в чём проблема? Задавайте в строке соединения `Application Name=MyAppName`

Comment: Требуется задавать в запросе, то есть после соединения, часть инструкций из скрипта, должны быть выполнены с другим app_name

Comment: Вряд ли это возможно. Согласно [спецификации TDS протокола](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/773a62b6-ee89-4c02-9e5e-344882630aac), AppName передаётся как часть LOGIN7 сообщения, т.е. только при установлении соединения. А средств для изменения AppName текущей сессии/соединения в SqlServer вроде бы нет.